# Reseeded Identity not showing in GUI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity

I am reseeding my Identity Seed with the following `T-SQL`:

```
USE DATABASENAME;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.DOCUMENT', RESEED, 400000000);
GO
```

I am subsequently checking it went through:

```
USE DATABASENAME; 
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.DOCUMENT', NORESEED); 
GO
```

But when I use the GUI it doesn't reflect my changes:
[image: GUI Snapshot]

It leaves me to believe that I have mixed up definitions and terms here and that I'm not actually changing what I think I'm changing.

Incidentally when I add a new row to the table `DOCUMENT` then the PK column shows a value starting at `400000000`.

Can someone explain what I am missing or is this a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: CHECKIDENT RESEED changes what the next value will be, not what the initial seed value was. To change the initial seed value as represented in the UI (why??? and why do you care what the UI says about this???), you'd have to drop the column and create a new one, or create a new table and migrate the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI is showing the result of looking at the table design, which shows `IDENTITY(1,1)` for the column in question.

Run the following code, then check the definition of the identity value by using the GUI; you will see the GUI reflects the design of the table, which is independent from the actual next value of the `IDENTITY` column.

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.IdentTest
(
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.IdentTest DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT * FROM dbo.IdentTest;

DBCC CHECKIDENT('IdentTest', RESEED, 400000000);

INSERT INTO dbo.IdentTest DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT * FROM dbo.IdentTest;
```

After running this, if you look at the GUI, you see:

[image]

If you "script" the design of the table; you get the following:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[IdentTest]    Script Date: 2015-10-27 4:54:15 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IdentTest](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Note the scripted table definition still shows `IDENTITY(1,1)`, since that is the *definition* of the table, which is unchanged by using `DBCC CHECKIDENT`.  The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) on `DBCC CHECKIDENT` says the following:

> Checks the current identity value for the specified table in SQL Server 2016 and, if it is needed, changes the identity value. You can also use DBCC CHECKIDENT to manually set a new current identity value for the identity column.

Note this does not mention anything about changing the definition of the table itself.

Comment: But doesn't my `T-SQL` change that seed value?

Comment: Yes, @tmwoods - the `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command *is* changing the  value of the *next* identity to be used.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to show all this! I was wondering if there is a way to change the definition itself. I can't find anything online to this end; the reason is because there are a few system admins here and since most would check via the GUI I'd like the change to be shown there.

Comment: Why are you "checking" the value, and then reseeding it?  This is not something that should ever be visible to the end-user so why do you care?  I'm asking this in case there is some situation you are attempting to resolve perhaps incorrectly.  Read about the [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem).

Comment: I am also worried I'm not understanding what is happening here. I don't understand what is different between using `DBCC CHECKIDENT` vs. changing that value in the GUI. Don't those two tasks accomplish the same outcome? And if so, why doesn't one reflect the other? The reason I care is because we have 3-4 sys admins here that will be checking through the GUI, not `DBCC CHECKIDENT`, so I want accurate information represented in both places.

Comment: What is the reason they are checking the identity values?  I've never *in my life* ever "checked" the values.

Comment: We have a checklist when we need to debug our application interface (the application layer isn't our design, we just follow the 'script'). If the subscription isn't set up properly it causes a few nightmares for the application.
My question still is though, what's the difference between using `DBCC CHECKIDENT` vs. the GUI?

Comment: As I said previously, the dbcc checkident command changes the next *value* whereas the GUI is displaying the definition of the *table design*.  They are two completely different things.